# Monitor application state perl

Tags: perl

Is there a way to monitor an app running so that if it is minimized or closed I will be notified? This is nothing nerfarious, I just want to have an app running on my computer but people keep closing it to use my computer when I am not around. Irritating really

Comment: I think you should use a screensaver that locks your screen instead.

Comment: That doesnt seem as fun... I know who is doing it and I kind of want to catch him at it since he denies it all the time

Comment: Plus the more I do things like this, the more practice I get at writing code. Its a win win situation

Comment: Just lock your computer and use a password that's hard to crack.

Comment: I am not asking for a fix to my computer user problems I want to know if it is possible to monitor the application state. What if someday I want it for something else?

Comment: @mob My operating system is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the process id of your app with `TASKLIST`. Then plug it into this one-liner:

```
perl -e "sleep 5 while kill 0,<PID>;system'explorer http://youtu.be/CsbYx6hevoQ'"
```

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that this is not possible, and is certainly not cross-platform, unless you write an application in Perl. For this, I would suggest the Prima toolkit as it is a cross-platform Perl GUI toolkit that is easy to install. Having a Prima application respond to a minimization or close event should be easy enough.